# Cannot access dependency which I don't use

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, dependencies, deserialization

I'm writing kafka consumer and use POJO's deserialiser. I don't use Jackson, but when compile there is an error that it can't be accessed

**ConsumerConfiguration.java**

```
package com.example.accountkafkaconsumer.Config;

import com.example.accountkafkaconsumer.Account;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Account> jsonConsumerFactory(){
        JsonDeserializer<Account> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Account.class);
        deserializer.setRemoveTypeHeaders(false);
        deserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
        deserializer.setUseTypeMapperForKey(true);

        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "json_group");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Account> accountKafkaListenerFactory(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Account> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(jsonConsumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }
}
```

**log**

/Users/fnikolaev/Desktop/Kafka course/AccountKafkaConsumer/src/main/java/com/example/accountkafkaconsumer/Config/ConsumerConfiguration.java:23:50
java: cannot access com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference
class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference not found

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>AccountKafkaConsumer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AccountKafkaConsumer</name>
    <description>AccountKafkaConsumer</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: apparently, one of the libraries you depend on does use it.

Comment: Try you build first on plain command line...

Comment: `JsonDeserializer` **does** use Jackson